# Could it be possible to override the "is_active" method from my user model?

Tags: python, django

In my forms.py file:

```py
class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = [
       "first_name",
       "last_name",
       "email",
       "username",
       "password1",
       "password2"
     ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a snippet of `User` model having `is_active` attribute-

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('active'), default=True)
```

Comment: And it won't reflect on that form being rendered to the frontend?